# Missing ) after argument list when trying to use importrange in app script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, string-concatenation

I'm trying to use google app script in google sheets to set a formula to importrange. I have the following code:

```
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getCurrentCell().setFormulaR1C1('=IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/blahblah","Completed Work!B5:N")');
```

My problem is when I try to make the code take an argument for the URL so when I say:

```
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getCurrentCell().setFormulaR1C1('=IMPORTRANGE('URL',"Completed Work!B5:N")');
```

When I try to run my function using:

```
myfunction("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/blahblah","Completed Work!B5:N")
```

I get a Missing ) after argument list error, how would I go about fixing the second formula so URL can be passed as an argument of the function?

Thanks!

Comment: For example, how about modifying to ``SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getCurrentCell().setFormulaR1C1('=IMPORTRANGE(' + URL + ',"Completed Work!B5:N")');``? If you want to also give ``"Completed Work!B5:N"``, how about ``SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getCurrentCell().setFormulaR1C1('=IMPORTRANGE(' + URL + ',"' + value + '")');``?

Comment: Hi Tanaike, 
Thanks for the help, the first suggestion worked right off the bat but I'm not sure why my attempt didn't work but your solution did, can you please give me a breakdown of what's happening in the code?

Comment: I'm really sorry for my incomplete comment. I think that @Rubén 's answer is helpful for you. Please check it. By the way, I noticed that ``'=IMPORTRANGE(' + URL + ',"Completed Work!B5:N")'`` occurs an error. So please modify to ``'=IMPORTRANGE("' + URL + '","Completed Work!B5:N")'``. Please enclose URL by double quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Short answer

Use the JavaScript string concatenation operator `+`

## Extended answer

You have to learn about string concatenation on JavaScript.

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String (follow the link to see the inline links)

> Strings are useful for holding data that can be represented in text form. Some of the most-used operations on strings are to check their length, to build and concatenate them using the `+` and `+=` string operators, checking for the existence or location of substrings with the `indexOf()` method, or extracting substrings with the `substring()` method.

Instead of

```
'=IMPORTRANGE('URL',"Completed Work!B5:N")'
```

use

```
'=IMPORTRANGE("' + URL + '","Completed Work!B5:N")'
```

NOTE: Pleas note the use of `"` to doble quote enclose the value of URL as it's required by IMPORTRANGE.

Comment: This is a nice explanation. I thought that the URL is required to be enclosed by double quotes like ``'=IMPORTRANGE("' + URL + '","Completed Work!B5:N")'``. How about this?

Comment: Thanks @Tanaike. That it's a lot better. (I think that nobody will  use something like `var URL = '"https:/.../"'`)

Comment: Thank you both, I will take a look at the documentation for string concatenation :)

Comment: @Rubén Thank you for replying and updating. Yes. Actually, OP uses ``myfunction("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/blahblah","Completed Work!B5:N")``. I would like to upvote.